# Trouble with Spring Data Repositories

Tags: java, spring, repository

It has been 2 days i am trying to work with Spring Data repositories and trying to setup a simple repository.

1. I have simple UserRepository using CrudRepository
2. I have my entity class
3. And here is my XML in which the highlighted line is giving me error in web browser

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">



       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
           <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
           <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"/>
           <property name="username" value="root"/>
           <property name="password" value=""/>
       </bean>    


       <jpa:repositories base-package="com.mydata"/>

       <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
           <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
           <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
           <property name="database" value="test"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
           <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
           <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
           <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
           <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mydata"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>    


   </beans>
   ```

When i access the controller in which i initilize this beans class i get following error in web browser

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database' for property 'database'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database] for property 'database': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

And this error occurs because of line in XML  **property name="database" value="test"**

Shahzad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try MYSQL database value? I think Spring should convert it implicitly to Database.MYSQL

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
</bean>
```

Or Spring Boot bean definition

```
@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The indicated in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/AbstractJpaVendorAdapter.html#setDatabase-org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database-) the `database` property takes the database type, not the name.

In general, I suggest to rather look at Spring Boot and its JPA support (find [a guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) here) as it svaes you from all the boilerplate configuration setup.